# Symfony2 catch PDO errors when booting Kernel

Tags: php, symfony, exception, pdo

I am using Symfony 2.4 and am trying to create a more powerful exceptions handler that, on certain PDO / Doctrine exceptions, changes the status code of the response from 500 to 503 to display a different custom error message than our standard (in other words, it returns the error503.html.twig template rather than error500.html.twig). So far, I have created a custom Exceptions controller that extends the TwigBundle ExceptionController, I have changed the Twig exception parameter in config.yml, and I am able to catch any and all exceptions that are thrown once Symfony calls `handle(...)` in HttpKernel.php:185 (so it's really the second time that `handle` is called -- this time being on the HttpKernel rather than the AppKernel). I'll refrain from posting all that code, and instead direct the reader [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#replace-the-default-exception-controller) to learn more about my method if they are unfamiliar. All of that code is working just fine -- I am able to modify any applications that are thrown within my application, so you can assume that I'm using the aforementioned approach properly.

The issue I am running into is that in addition to catching exceptions that are thrown within Symfony, I also want to also be able to catch exceptions that are thrown before the HttpKernel's `handle` method is called (an example being a PDO Access Denied exception that is thrown from improper database credentials). To give you a more specific rundown, in `app_dev.php`, you have:

```
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

which calls:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @api
 */
public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
{
    if (false === $this->booted) {
        $this->boot();
    }

    return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);
}
```

Now, if an exception gets thrown in `$this->boot()`, it doesn't look like it gets caught anywhere, and because of that, I can't see any way of gracefully handling said exception in Symfony. It's only if the exception gets thrown within the try / catch block contained in `$this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch)` that it will be caught and gracefully handled using Symfony code. Am I wrong about that? Does anyone know of an approach to handling exceptions that are thrown in this context that utilizes Symfony? My apologies in advance if this has already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem, I didn't see a neat way around this but was able to get nice error pages for my specific problem simply by generating a Response object and sending that. I placed the following in some code which was called by boot()

```
try {
    someExceptionFunction();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response = new Response('<html><body>'.$e->getMessage().'</body></html>');
    $response->send();
    exit;
}
```

You could easily add some more logic to the catch block, catching different exceptions. It's not as clean/abstract as it could be, but since the entire framework fails to boot I don't know of any option you could use it to parse an error page.

Hope this helps